# Check if library is available in Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, include, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I need to transfer a big library to Linux and this was developed under Windows - with windows-specific libraries. Because there are many I don't want to bother Stackoverflow about this ;). But what would be an easy way to check all the *includes* of all the header files in that given case?

Is there some kind of a list or a platform in the internet to look it up?
E.g. `is <conio.h> available in Linux?` --> `no it isn't, use this alternative ...` or am I forced to search for it in 100 of webpages.

Thanks for any advise

Comment: It is not possible to state if some header file is generall available "under Linux". That obviously is a question of what packages (or even files) you install on a system. Then you have to consider that files with the same name may hold completely different content. So your best bet simply is to start compilation and react to the error messages you receive.

Comment: @arkascha in generall yes - but I still hope there is a *deviation* for the most common ones like `conio.h`

Comment: Since there literally exist hundreds of millions of packages for Linux this is impossible in my eyes. but what is the issue, why invest into processing an endless list manually if you can simply use the compiler to do that?

Comment: @arkascha well on the other hand it comes in handy if you get the advise what library does the same job *and* runs on x,y,z ... OS

Comment: Sure, don't get me wrong. I have nothing against information being available :-) But I don't see how that should be possible. you have to consider that the huge number of libraries (or software in general) is offered, implemented and maintained by different parties. There is no central organization behind all that. So who should compile such lists and decide what replacement options are valid and make sense? There is no such thing as a central development environment you can rely on.

Comment: @arkascha that's right, but I'm talking and hoping about a thing, where stackexchange is build up on. I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one wondering.... but apparently nobody ever started

Comment: Pretty certainly such recommendation list never really been started, except obviously for some internal project with focus on the libraries of interest there. Though even internally: once you know that, what is the sense in making a list? Besides the question of responsibility or motivation I see quite some questions that I could not really answer: for example: what does it mean: some library is a replacement for a library? Almost in 100% of all cases there will be differences. Since there is a reason why there are separate libraries. Sorry, as said: does not work.